# Windows 8 - rename to overwrite file

Tags: windows-8, file-management

Is it still possible if I have files

```
foo
bar
```

to rename file `bar` to `foo` and overwrite it?

My Windows 8 asks me if I want to rename `bar` to `foo (2)` and it's driving me crazy. It doesn't bother me on my own PC as I use Total Commander for file management, but on other PCs this happens.

Answer (score 2):

No, it has never been possible on Windows as far as I can remember.

You have to do it in 2 phases. Something like foo to foo2 then bar to foo then foo2 to foo.

Comment: huh, I remember that it has always been possible (at least up to Vista, but I don't have any older Windows around)

Comment: Well it is possible that my memory is failing me (happens all too often at my age!) but I don't remember being able to do this, it would be far too easy to entirely mess up a complete drive doing that with a very simple script.